# need to remove fill icon and replace unfill icon only for dashboard icon(first icon in image)

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOY77.png)

app.routing module.ts:

```
{path: '', component: DashboardComponent},
{ path:'test', canActivate: [AuthGuard], loadChildren: () => 
 import('./test/test.module').then(m => m.testModule)},
 .
 .
```

In the image there are 5 icons the first icon was dashboard page and second was test and so on.. now when i click on second or third icon the image will be filled and rest be unfilled. but the dashboard icon remains same even i have added the filled and unfilled icons.

sidebar.component.ts:

```
 .lock-icon {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    display: block;
    //padding-left: 20px;
    }

    .lock-icon:after {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     height: 18px; /*height of icon */
     width: 18px; /*width of icon */
     position: absolute;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     /*where to replace the icon */
     /*background */
     background-image: url("../../../../assets/icons/lock.svg");
     }


   .lock-icon-active {
   height: 18px;
   width: 18px;
   display: block;
   //padding-left: 20px;
   }

  .lock-icon-active:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 18px; /*height of icon */
  width: 18px; /*width of icon */
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  /*where to replace the icon */
  /*background */
 background-image: url("../../../../assets/icons/lockfilled.svg");
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really you give us very few clues. So I imagine you are using routerLink if you has a .css like

```
.active .fill{
  display:inline-block;
}
.fill{
  display:none
}
.active .unfill{
  display:none;
}
```

Your routerlinks can be like -I use span, use you icons-

```
  <a routerLink="/yourpath" routerLinkActive="active" >
       <span class="fill">NEW</span>
       <span class="unfill">new</span>
  </a>
```

NOTE: routerLink **not only** works on `<a>`, you can use other tags like `<div>` `<button>`,`<li>`...

Comment: i am not using any router link... and added css class of sidebar. please have a look i am applying the same class for all icons on side bar everything was working fine. only the empty path(first icon) it was showing always active.

Comment: first use only `url("assets/icons/lockfilled.svg");`, after, sory I don't know how you change the css, are you using some like `[ngClass]="path=='lock'?''lock-icon-active':lock-icon'"`?